# Error inflating class TextView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fatal-error, inflate-exception

I have Recycler View inside Fragment and data in ArrayList But when I run my Application some how it throws an exception like InflateException. I tried lot but not getting anysolution.

It would be great if any one can solve and i will be very thankful.

Here is logcat.

```
com.example.ankitsodha.aroundme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ankitsodha.aroundme, PID: 9678
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class TextView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.example.ankitsodha.aroundme.MyRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyRecyclerAdapter.java:29)
    at com.example.ankitsodha.aroundme.MyRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyRecyclerAdapter.java:15)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5228)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4453)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
    at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:166
```

MyRecyclerAdapter.java

```
    public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<PlaceModalClass> placeData;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PlaceModalClass> placeData)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.placeData=placeData;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item,parent,false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.tvName.setText(placeData.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return placeData.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        TextView tvName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        }
    }
}
```

recycler_row_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>        
</LinearLayout>
```

MyFragment.java File

```
recyclerview=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
MyRecyclerAdapter adapter=new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),placeData);
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: yes this if full stack trace

Comment: Can you post your activity/fragment code. The sample you have posted seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your recycler_row_item.xml delete the below line.

android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

or replace it by this:

`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`

Comment: Yes I know about Layout Manager and I already have set Linear Layout Manager still it is showing the same error

Comment: can you post your xml code of recycler_row_item, or check the Line no 8 of this file

Comment: I have already posted recycler_row_item xml file just check above. There is one Text View inside Linear Layout.